# In R, ggplot2, how can I map one column to fill aesthetics and other column to fill color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with four columns (YearMonth, Sales, Client, HexColor) on which my column plot is based.

YearMonth is mapped to x, Sales is mapped to y, and Client is mapped to fill. However, I want fill color to be mapped to HexColor (provided that each Client has one only HexColor.

How can I have fill mapped to one column and fill color set with values of other column?

Eg.:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  YearMonth = c("2024-01", "2024-01", "2024-01", "2024-02"),
  Client = c("Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company A"),
  Sales = c(3510, 1749.5, 1257, 1133.92),
  HexColor = c("#A6CEE3", "#1F78B4", "#B2DF8A", "#A6CEE3")
)

#This shows correct legend but not the colors I want:
ggplot(data = mydata) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x=YearMonth, y=Sales, fill=Client))

#This shows correct colors, but not the legend I want:
ggplot(data = mydata) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x=YearMonth, y=Sales, fill=HexColor)) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `scale_fill_manual()`?

```
ggplot(data = mydata) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = YearMonth, y = Sales, fill = Client)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Company A" = "#A6CEE3", "Company B" = "#1F78B4", "Company C" = "#B2DF8A"))
```

[image]

Comment: why not `scale_fill_manual(values = mydata$HexColor)`?

Comment: @Onyambu That's better

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Creating a named vector and passing it as values parameter of scale_fill_manual did the trick.